# 80s song with reverb drums, "hu", "ho" vocal sample

Tags: identify-this-song

All I remember is it has big drums, pop, dance (maybe), big gated reverb drums. The kick would go then the snare, and on the snare it would have a vocal sample that alternated "hu", "ho", " hu", "ho". I've listened to about 50 songs today trying to find it.

Comment: I think all 80s songs had reverb on the drums. :)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

This may be "Big Love" by Fleetwood Mac from 1987. Big drums, loads of gated reverb, "hu"/"ho" repeated whenever there's an instrumental break.